# How to deep-freeze redux state in react redux application?

Tags: redux, react-redux, immutability

I need to deep freeze the whole redux state in react redux application using deep-freeze library to check for any mutation on state.
How should I use deep-freeze with react redux app to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume you mean you're looking to use deep-freeze as a testing tool for changes (as I'm not sure why you would want to freeze the entire state).  All the while there a handful of examples out there.

Typically you use deep-freeze with expect and you focus on your reducers because reducers are given a state and they return an expected state.

A typical test usually looks something like this ([taken from here](https://codepen.io/ilkka/pen/yeLGwv)):

```
// a test for the reducer
const testReducer = () => {
    const stateBefore = { value: 'foo' };
    const action = {
        type: 'SET_STATE',
        value: 'bar'
    };
    const stateAfter = { value: 'bar' };

    // cannot modify
    deepFreeze(stateBefore);
    deepFreeze(action);

    expect(store(stateBefore, action)).toEqual(stateAfter);
}
```

In this way, you're verifying that actions taken do not alter your state in any way.

Egghead.io also has a good video on this [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread).

Of course, the usage doesn't have to be limited to tests; you could introduce deep-freeze as an assertion tool throughout your code as well I supposed if you want.  I've not personally got any experience doing that.

Comment: Thanks. I want to use deep freeze in development mode. Since the whole state must be Immutable, I decided to use deep freeze to check to see if I am mutating the state or not and if I am mutating it, where in the code the mutation happens.

Comment: So you are saying that it is not possible to deep freeze the whole state to check for mutation? and/or it is not the right way to use deep freeze with redux?